# Autoroute reference error after installing new theme in orchard CMS 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms

I use orchard cms 1.10.1, After I installed a theme from orchard galley, got a compiler error "missing reference Orchard.Autoroute.Models".

So i Added "Orchard.AutoRoute" project reference to "Theme Project" to fix this error. Errors gone but it still doesn't build and Error list in visual studio does't show any error.

How can i fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to clean then rebuild the solution

Comment: Tried clean & rebuild, didn't work

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: out put window shows this "========== Rebuild All: 84 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========".

Comment: and error list is empty

Comment: Maybe it is an old theme, which one did you install?

Comment: Tera and Metro , these were in top 5 themes

Comment: Just deleted the themes from solution and it buillt. but I need new themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `Microsoft.Csharp.dll` to "Theme Project" references and it fixed the issue.